# Coffeeescript: Comparison of two nested arrays with objects as elements not working

Tags: coffeescript

Returns false, but expecting to be true:

```
verify = [1,2,3]
res      = [
                aktuell:
                    dp:1
                aktuell:
                    dp:2
                aktuell:
                    dp:3
                ]

arrayEqual = (a, b) ->
  a.length is b.length and a.every (elem, i) -> elem is b[i].aktuell.dp

document.write arrayEqual verify, res
```

http://codepen.io/nottinhill/pen/jPOyMM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works:

```
res = 
[
  aktuell: dp: 1
,
  aktuell: dp: 2
,
  aktuell: dp: 3
]
```

Pay attention to the placement and intend of the commatas.

Compiles to:

```
var res;

res = [
  {
    aktuell: {
      dp: 1
    }
  }, {
    aktuell: {
      dp: 2
    }
  }, {
    aktuell: {
      dp: 3
    }
  }
];
```

And for Classes and Objects:

```
myClass
    count: ->
        {
            objectA: 
                objectA-2:['a-2-list']
            objectB: 
                objectB-2:'b-2-string'
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function works just fine. Your Definition of the object isn't:

compiled object definition:

```
 res = [
    {
      aktuell: {
        dp: 1
      },
      aktuell: {
        dp: 2
      },
      aktuell: {
        dp: 3
      }
    }
  ]
```

And with that, you'll get an Array with one object and your `every` part doesn't get executed.

You'll have to use the curly braces.